# Nodejs appears to return a response before waiting for functions containing Promises to resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express

I am trying to hit my API endpoint 'categories' to return a list of documents from my categories collection in firebase. Using the following code:

```
function getCategories() {
  let arr = [];
  categories
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data().category);
        arr.push(doc.data().category);
        return arr;
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return [1, 2, 3];
    });
}

router.route("/categories").get(async function(req, res, next) {
  let arr = await getCategories();
  res.json(arr);
});
```

While I don't get any errors I receive an empty response which when debugged shows that `arr` is undefined. The thing is when using the debugger the console logs inside the `forEach` get called and I see my categories in the console but for some reason, it doesn't wait for the Firebase Promise to resolve and the router just responds with an undefined `arr` variable.

Comment: You don't return the promise chain from getCategories...

Comment: to expand on that, your `getCategories` only has returns inside promise handlers. Those `return` statements will return _from each handler_, and not from `getCategories`. Since it has no `return` of its own, the result of calling `getCategories` is `undefined`, while the Promise resolves separately from your function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.then` callback should look more like this (there is no need for a separate `arr` variable):

```
function getCategories() {
  // notice we are returning the promise
  return categories
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      // notice we are returning the new array using .map()
      return snapshot.map(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data().category);
        return doc.data().category;
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return [1, 2, 3];
    });
}
```

And since you are using async/await already, you can rewrite this all to look like this so that your users can know when an error happened:

```
// notice the function is now async
async function getCategories() {
    const snapshot = await categories.get()
    // this can be a one-liner in the example above too
    return snapshot.map(doc => doc.data().category);
}

router.route("/categories").get(async function(req, res, next) {
   try {
     let arr = await getCategories();
     res.json(arr);
   } catch(ex) {
     res.status(500).json({ msg: ex.message });
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! just need to point out to use the `.map` we need to use `snapshot.docs` not just `snapshot` I didn't think of using this function before makes evrything cleaner thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning your promise and value inside the `.then`. Add `return` in front of `categories.get()` call and return value inside then.

Answer (score 1):

`getCategories` needs to return a promise if you want to use `await` on it.  Right now, it's returning nothing.  You'll need to return the promise that you created:

```
function getCategories() {
  let arr = [];
  return categories
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data().category);
        arr.push(doc.data().category);
        return arr;
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return [1, 2, 3];
    });
}
```

Note the `return` keyword.

You also possibly have another problem here.  You're iterating the snapshot using `forEach`, and returning `arr` from within the lambda function that you passed to `forEach`.  This will not return the snapshot data to the caller. You will need to return a value from the `then` lambda:

```
    .then(snapshot => {
      const arr = []
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data().category);
        arr.push(doc.data().category);
      });
      return arr;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
function getCategories() {
  let arr = [];
  categories
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data().category);
        arr.push(doc.data().category);
        });
        console.log('arr',arr); //check the array data
        return arr;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return [1, 2, 3];
    });
}

router.route("/categories").get(async function(req, res, next) {
  let arr = await getCategories().catch(err => {
         res.status(400).send(err);
   });
  res.json(arr);
});
```